# JavaScript: Higher Order Function that Calls Add Function to Return New Array; Error: 'NaN' elements in output array

Tags: javascript, arrays, return, closures, higher-order-functions

I have a function 'sometimes' and want to return a function object from it.

Below is my code:

```
let add = (a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  };

myFunc = sometimes(add);

const outputArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      outputArr.push(myFunc(2 + i, 3 + i));
    }

function sometimes (inputFunc){
  return function (a, b){
    return inputFunc()
  }
}

outputArr
```

I expect my outputArr variable to equal:

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

Instead mine equals:

```
 [ NaN, NaN, NaN ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did not pass any arguments. Should be `return inputFunc(a, b)`

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the parameters to the wrapped function. The `add` function tries to sum two `undefined` values and the result is `NaN` (not a number).

You have to pass the parameters to the wrapped function:

```
 return function(a, b) {
    return inputFunc(a, b); // <<<
 }
```

Since `sometimes` is a higher order function, that needs to wrap different functions, with a changing number of parameters, it can't know the implementation of the wrapped function. To ensure that, you should use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) (to collect the parameters to an array) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (to convert the array back to parameters) to pass the arguments to the wrapped function.

```js
let add = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};

myFunc = sometimes(add);

const outputArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  outputArr.push(myFunc(2 + i, 3 + i));
}

function sometimes(inputFunc) {
  return function(...args) {
    return inputFunc(...args)
  }
}

console.log(outputArr);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your code as

```
    function sometimes(a,b){
    return a + b;
}

const outputArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      outputArr.push(sometimes(2 + i, 3 + i));

    }
console.log(outputArr);
```

now the output is

```
[ 5, 7, 9 ]
```

Comment: I think you are missing the "higher order function" part of the question.